# Непонятная кострукция в SQL запросе

Tags: sql

Продолжаю переносить в php хранимые процедуры.
В одной наткнулся на вот такой запрос:

```
WHILE ( i < node_cnt ) DO
    SET i = i + 1;

    INSERT  `tblnodesaccount`( `plc_id`, `node_num`, `active` )
    VALUES( in_plc_id, i, i = 1 );
  END WHILE;
```

Меня смущает "**i = 1**".
Не должно ли это приводить к вечному циклу?

Comment: Может, это не присваивание, а сравнение? Тип колонки `active` случайно не `BOOLEAN`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никакого бесконечного цикла не будет, т.к. при вставке изменения значения переменной не происходит. i=1 - это логическое выражение и, судя по всему, в таблицу будет записано что-то типа true/false (0/1).

Answer (score 1):

Какая СУБД ? В MS SQL Server аналогичный запрос по идее должен выдавать ошибку в том месте, которое вас cмущает - "i = 1", т.к. присвоить какое-то значение переменной мы должны с помощью ключевого слова set.

Comment: MySQL. Ошибки не происходит.